# IPOPT finds the optimal solution on the second solve

Tags: matlab, optimization, ampl, ipopt

usually when I try to solve sth with IPOPT, even if the problem is infeasible, IPOPT shows the running process and for example shows how many constraints the problem have and other general information of the problem but this time I was faced a strange problem. first time that I solve the problem it shows nothing, but the second time that I solve it, IPOPT returns optimal solution. like this:

```
-> ampl.eval('option solver ipopt ;'); 
-> ampl.solve()
```

(it returns nothing here!!!!)

```
-> solve_result  = ampl.getValue('solve_result_num')
solve_result = -1
```

so here, I just run the code again:

```
 -> ampl.solve()
Ipopt 3.12.4: 
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
     For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************
This is Ipopt version 3.12.4, running with linear solver mumps.
NOTE: Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).
Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     4439
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:     7888
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:       50
Total number of variables............................:     1610
                 variables with only lower bounds:        0
            variables with lower and upper bounds:       70
                 variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:     1360  
Total number of inequality constraints...............:     2585
    inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:     2585
    inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
0  5.0001000e+03 1.31e+00 8.32e-02  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
1  5.0079602e+03 1.31e+00 2.71e+01  -1.0 1.68e+01    -  1.05e-02 7.73e-04f  1
2  3.9278729e+03 1.17e+00 9.17e+00  -1.0 1.24e+00    -  3.65e-02 9.32e-02f  1
3  2.7624370e+03 9.13e-01 2.49e+01  -1.0 4.52e-01    -  7.04e-01 1.99e-01f  1
4  1.6350590e+03 7.87e-02 2.17e+01  -1.0 6.17e-01    -  2.98e-01 7.82e-01f  1
5  8.6271513e+02 3.73e-13 2.34e-01  -1.0 1.53e-01    -  9.90e-01 1.00e+00f  1
6  1.0292941e+03 1.98e-13 8.49e-13  -1.0 1.03e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
7  1.0259140e+03 1.86e-13 6.85e-13  -2.5 6.57e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
8  9.1964915e+02 2.02e-13 7.11e-04  -3.8 1.84e-02    -  9.96e-01 1.00e+00f  1
9  3.5639825e+02 2.30e-13 4.23e-02  -5.7 9.45e-02    -  7.68e-01 1.00e+00f  1
 iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls

10  7.9479322e+01 2.23e-13 9.26e-03  -5.7 1.85e-01    -  8.95e-01 1.00e+00f  1
11  1.9247063e+01 2.72e-13 2.80e-14  -5.7 1.19e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
12  6.9889052e+00 3.55e-13 9.99e-05  -8.6 4.59e-02    -  9.33e-01 1.00e+00f  1
13  1.2789711e+00 4.20e-13 4.22e-04  -8.6 2.96e-01    -  4.85e-01 8.98e-01f  1
14  2.9354384e-01 2.00e-13 6.84e-06  -8.6 4.49e-02    -  9.92e-01 1.00e+00f  1
15  1.0626050e-01 2.41e-13 7.17e-14  -8.6 9.55e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
16  6.3028082e-02 3.77e-13 5.27e-14  -8.6 1.37e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
17  4.3933480e-03 3.27e-13 6.90e-08 -11.0 2.32e-03    -  9.99e-01 1.00e+00h  1
18  1.1280540e-03 2.81e-13 8.08e-14 -11.0 1.02e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
19  3.9735544e-04 3.93e-13 5.46e-14 -11.0 5.59e-05    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
20  2.2989758e-04 3.19e-13 1.68e-14 -11.0 2.72e-05    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Number of Iterations....: 20
                               (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   2.4678359201693643e-10    2.2989757642660348e-04
Dual infeasibility......:   1.6794654637445761e-14    1.5645490717250029e-08
Constraint violation....:   2.7491418973006631e-15    3.1883523599063324e-13
Complementarity.........:   5.3838886983188674e-11    5.0154994235157414e-05
Overall NLP error.......:   5.3838886983188674e-11    5.0154994235157414e-05
Number of objective function evaluations             = 21
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 21
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 21
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 21
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 21
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 21
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 20
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.295
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.004
EXIT: Optimal So 
Ipopt 3.12.4: Optimal Solution Found
suffix ipopt_zU_out OUT;
suffix ipopt_zL_out OUT;
-> solve_result  = ampl.getValue('solve_result_num')
solve_result =  0
```

so can anyone know why this happens and what is the meaning of this?